# How to extract numerical named property from a JSON parsed object in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps Script

```
Utilities.jsonParse('{"1":"123","a":"abc"}')["a"] // "abc"
Utilities.jsonParse('{"1":"123","a":"abc"}')["1"] // undefined
```

In Google Chrome JavaScrpt Console

```
JSON.parse('{"1":"123","a":"abc"}')["a"] // "abc"
JSON.parse('{"1":"123","a":"abc"}')["1"] // "123"
```

Is this a bug?
How can I extract a numerical named property from JSON object in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilities.jsonParse has some oddities surrounding numeric keys. Prefer the newer (and more standard) `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` instead:

```
JSON.parse('{"1":"123","a":"abc"}')["1"]  // "123"
```

Comment: The JSON class doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, and it doesn't appear when using Ctrl+Space auto-complete. Any chance of some documentation?

Comment: It's not an Apps Script class - it's part of standard JavaScript, like Math or Date. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but does this return anything different:

```
Utilities.jsonParse('{"1":"123","a":"abc"}')[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But your solution also returns `undefined` in Google Apps Script.